# seo meta description issue in google search

Tags: php, html, wordpress, seo, meta

This is my first time to use Yoast SEO plugin in my website, I'm trying to add meta description to every pages and every post in my website.

When I search it on google, seems like the meta description does not show at all, instead google take the content from the website page as the meta description.

When I looked at the page source, there is a content that I set in Yoast SEO as my meta description

this is my website

> [sunlitex.co.id/en/](http://sunlitex.co.id)

I already change  tag in my page to be like this to match with the SEO

```
<title><?php if ( is_category() ) {
    echo 'Category Archive for &quot;'; single_cat_title(); echo '&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    echo 'Tag Archive for &quot;'; single_tag_title(); echo '&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_archive() ) {
    wp_title(''); echo ' Archive | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_search() ) {
    echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    bloginfo( 'name' ); echo ' | '; bloginfo( 'description' );
}  elseif ( is_404() ) {
    echo 'Error 404 Not Found | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_single() ) {
    wp_title('');
} else {
    echo wp_title( ' | ', false, right ); bloginfo( 'name' );
} ?>
</title>
```

Is there any reference that can explain/help me to make the meta description work?

Is there any settings that I need to change from the plugin section?

I also have a question for meta description template from the plugin page, do I just leave it blank or should I add some variables?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/218277/34147).

Comment: Are you sure the meta description gets saved? The latest version came with some issues. See [this explanation](http://www.insight-things.com/yoast-metadescription-workaround) for more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. It's best to think of the meta description as a default or a fallback in the absence of more relevant page content. Google is most concerned with delivering content that is of most relevance to a user's specific search and will always use the actual page content when it can to show users what to expect if they visit the page. The old model, of displaying the meta description in search results, is a relic from a time when the web was catalogued more like a massive directory. There's ample info on this but I recommend checking out Matt Cutts' videos for related info.

Comment: thank you for your response. I just want to check with you for keywords part that I put in my SEO, when I test it in SERPs, the keywords seems does not work at all, SERPs couldn't match the keywords that I enter with the keywords that already set in my SEO. Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: When you say the keywords don't work, do you mean that you're not ranking as highly as you like? And when you say that you set the keywords in your SEO, are the keywords organically part of the page content? It takes time and, more importantly, quality inbound links to really rise in search rank, especially when trying to rank for competitive keywords. If the keywords are not in content-rich pages or are confined to things like meta descriptions, Google will assume it's a low quality source for the term.

Comment: But getting quality links is the real key. If people legitimately link to you (i.e., you're not exchanging links for the sake of sharing links), and especially if domains with high authority link to you, Google will give your pages and domain higher weight to compete with other sites using the same keywords. SEO is not what it used to be, and in fact once you've done a decent job optimizing your content, SEO tweaking will probably hurt more than help. Now it's time to focus on content and getting good links.

Comment: I really got a lot of information from you, thank you so much for your explanation :)